# Antd Select not working in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, antd

I have been using antd for my new project. All the components are working fine on the web and mobile except the antd select. It's not working on mobile . Please share the solutions

```
<Select
  defaultValue={"undefined"}
  style={{ width: 130 }}
  onChange={(e) => handleSelectEmployee(e, index, "employeeChange")} >
  {service[0].map((service, index) => {
    return (
      <Option value={service.id} key={index}>
        {service.name}
      </Option>
    );
  })}
</Select>;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What do you mean by “not working”?

Comment: Does [their example](https://ant.design/components/select/) works for you on mobile? Doesn't it work on all mobile devices? What exactly is not working?

Comment: @evolutionxbox  When I click an option its not getting slected in mobile devices . Its working fine in PC

Comment: @MoshFeu I have tried the same example mentioned . If i click the option alternately for 100 times , any one  gets selected

Answer (score 0):

Finally I issue is solved . The issue exist in antd version 4.4.2 .After the version is updated to 4.13.0 it works fine in mobile devices